# How do I fix "Extra argument in call" when decoding with required convenience init?(coder:)?

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

I am relatively new to app development and am trying to add persistence to a homework management app written using SwiftUI. I am implementing NSCoding in my "UserData" class and was able to create the encode function with no problems, but after I set up the decoding function I am getting an error "Extra arguments 'assignments' in call" on the self.init() line. What exactly is wrong with my code?

```swift
class UserData: NSObject, NSCoding, ObservableObject {

    // MARK:- Properties

    @Published var assignments: [Assignment]
    @Published var courses: [Course] = []

    @Published var username: String = ""
    @Published var appState: AppState = AppState(willPresentSplashScreen: false)

...

 // MARK:- NSCoding

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(assignments, forKey: PropertyKey.assignments)
        coder.encode(courses, forKey: PropertyKey.courses)
        coder.encode(username, forKey: PropertyKey.username)
        coder.encode(appState, forKey: PropertyKey.appState)
    }

    required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {

        let assignments = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.assignments) as? [Assignment]
        let courses = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.courses) as? [Course]
        let username = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.username) as? String
        let appState = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.appState) as? AppState

        self.init(assignments: assignments, courses: courses, username: username, appState: appState)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserData` is a class, and classes, unlike structs, do not get a default member-wise initialiser.  You need to create an initialiser that accepts those parameters.  Without it, the closest initialiser that Swift can find is `init()` that was inherited from `NSObject` - except the parameter names don't match so it gives an error.

You need to create the member-wise initialiser:

```
init(assignments: [Assignment], courses: [Course], username: String, appState: AppState) {
    self.assignments = assignments
    self.courses = courses
    self.username = username
    self.appState = appState
}
```

This will then give you an error that the parameters you are passing from `init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)` need to be unwrapped, as you have optionals and the initialiser doesn't expect optionals.

`init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)` is a failable initialiser, so you can return `nil` if everthing isn't right:

```
required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {

        guard let assignments = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.assignments) as? [Assignment],
            let courses = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.courses) as? [Course],
            let username = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.username) as? String,
            let appState = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.appState) as? AppState else {
                return nil
        }

        self.init(assignments: assignments, courses: courses, username: username, appState: appState)
}
```

I would probably get rid of the default values assigned to `courses`, `username` and `appState` - you don't need them as the values will come from the initialiser

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it for me. Why is it that my parameters are optionals even though I haven't explicitly declared them as such?

Comment: Because you used `as?` - a conditional downcast produces an optional